# Jquery div on screen pop up

Tags: jquery

Im trying to create a div on screen pop up. This is ok using istockphp.com's jquery code. The question is how can I make this happen with a button rather than a link.

This is the jsfiddle for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/DtB8C/

The link code:

```
<a href="#" class="topopup">Click Here Trigger</a>
```

The button code: (not working)

```
<input name="popup" type="button" value="popup" class="topopup" onClick="self.location='#'" style="width:7em">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share your script?

Comment: see the jsfiddle, it shows it there

Comment: Just change `$("a.topopup")` to `$(".topopup")` in the script.

Comment: Boy stack really needs a filter.. if you're using jQuery just target the appropriate element or class.. if you're hard coding with inline script, just change the onClick to whatever HTML element..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here. is this what you need?

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/DtB8C/2/

I've added this piece of code

```
$("input.topopup").click(function() {
    loading(); // loading
    setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup(); // function show popup 
    }, 500); // .5 second
    return false;
});
```

on the top of `script.js`. This will trigger the same behaviour you have on a `a.topopup` click, when you click on that particular `input`.

Comment: ahh of course, I didn't realise the code. This works great and is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution would be to hide your link and call it indirectly when clicking the button i.e.

```
$("input.topopup").click(function() {
            $("a.topopup").click();
    });
```

The other solution would be to modify a bit the code from istockphp and replace the "a.topopup" from the 3rd line with input.topopup or whatever you like.

```
/* 
    author: istockphp.com
*/
jQuery(function($) {

    $("a.topopup").click(function() {
            loading(); // loading
            setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
                loadPopup(); // function show popup 
            }, 500); // .5 second
    return false;
    });

    /* event for close the popup */
    $("div.close").hover(
                    function() {
                        $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                    },
                    function () {
                        $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                    }
                );

    $("div.close").click(function() {
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    });

    $(this).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
            disablePopup();  // function close pop up
        }   
    });

    $("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    });

    $('a.livebox').click(function() {
        alert('Hello World!');
    return false;
    });


     /************** start: functions. **************/
    function loading() {
        $("div.loader").show();  
    }
    function closeloading() {
        $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');  
    }

    var popupStatus = 0; // set value

    function loadPopup() { 
        if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
            closeloading(); // fadeout loading
            $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
            $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001); 
            popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
        }   
    }

    function disablePopup() {
        if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
            $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
            popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
        }
    }
    /************** end: functions. **************/
}); // jQuery End
```